# Live calculation doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I'm doing some live calculations while user typing.

It's weird, it works in jsfiddle but not in localhost.

```
window.onload = function() {

    var base = 10;
    var numberField = document.getElementById('numberField');

    numberField.onkeyup = numberField.onpaste = function() {

        if(this.value.length == 0) {

            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = '';
            return;

        }

        var number = parseInt(this.value);

        if(isNaN(number)) return;

        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = number * base;

    };

    numberField.onkeyup(); //could just as easily have been onpaste();
};
```

Comment: Maybe post the working jsfiddle.

Comment: thiss is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Dem6Q/176/

Answer (score 0):

You are listening to the wrong event, onkeyup. Instead you should listen to .change which is triggered when the whole field changes and after the user finishes typing and the input field loses focus or is blurred.

Quick example:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $(":input").change(function () {
         //do something
     });
 });
```

Another thing is rather use jquery than javascript. It will save you a lot of headaches.

Comment: ive tried this tooo but it just doesnt work ..

 $(".bayar5").keyup(function()  // explanation code section
    {
        if(this.value.length == 0) {  // explanation code section
         document.getElementById('kembali5').innerHTML = ''; // explanation code section
     return;
      }
          var bayar5= parseInt(this.value);
         if(isNaN(bayar5)) return;
          document.getElementById('kembali5').innerHTML = bayar5-total5 ; // explanation code section


       }); // explanation code section

Comment: also read up on the documentation for .change before trying to use it   http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: try doing it inside a global function  $(function() { }); or if it is a mobile device add a device ready listener, but please use the .change function because listening on keyup will not help in this case